# "Errors exist in the active configuration..." Eclipse Dialog when Debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

An "Errors exist in the active configuration of project X. Proceed with launch?" dialog appears while debugging code in Eclipse. Hitting the "Proceed" button results in successful debugging. There are no apparent errors with the launch configuration. A similar Run Configuration does not generate the error.

Comment: Cleaning and recompiling the project removed the error for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by an invalid path somewhere in your Eclipse project settings. There are a couple common sources for this kind of error.

1. You're working on a shared (version controlled, copied, etc) project where someone has hardcoded a path that doesn't exist on your machine, or uses an environment variable that you've not set.

Sometimes, you can find the offending path by looking at the full list of Error messages. If not, look in your project file.

2. The Discovery Options in your project properties has 'Automate discovery of paths and symbols' enabled - but the process is generating an error.

If you're using a version of Eclipse that warns you this option is deprecated, uncheck the option to disable it and fix any includes in 'Preprocessor Include Paths' instead. If not. . .try it anyway.

Depending on your path changes, restart Eclipse and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It starts the executable that was built last before you broke the build. That executable will be older then your source files. The reason you were able to debug is because your line numbers did not change for the code you've debugged - e.g. you may try break in main then introduce a compilation error and move main a couple lines below - the debug will highlight the wrong lines when it stops.

Comment: If the build is broken, a Run Configuration would fail.